# XSLT Error Could not load stylesheet: Operator or ')' expected

Tags: xslt-2.0

Need assistance/expert advice with error: Could not load stylesheet.com.sap.engine.lib.xsl.xpath.XPathException: Operator or ')' expected, whenever system tries to XSLT.

Below is my XSLT Code:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="MT_RemittanceAdvice/body/article" group-by="site">
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="\\phvsvrftp01\SM\DEV\RA\IN\RA_{position()}-output.xml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="MT_RemittanceAdvice/body/article">
    <xsl:if test=" .intersect current-group()">
        <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I am able to run this XSLT successfully using ALTOVA XMLSPY

Below is my source XML

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MT_RemittanceAdvice>
<header>
  <companyName>Dept Store</companyName>
  <DocumentType>Remittance Advice</DocumentType>
  <postDate>06/01/2017 03:27:16</postDate>
  <payeeName>xxxxxxxxxxxx</payeeName>
  <checkDate>05/31/2017</checkDate>
  <checkNumber>6321713</checkNumber>
  <region/>
  <amount>13,570.80</amount>
</header>
<body>
   <article>
        <transCode/>
        <poNumber>2023090</poNumber>
        <docRef/>
        <site>MY SHOPPINGLANE CEBU, CORP</site>
        <grossAmount>55.80</grossAmount>
        <discount>-0.50</discount>
        <netAmount>-55.30</netAmount>
   </article>
   <article>
        <transCode/>
        <poNumber>210205</poNumber>
        <docRef/>
        <site>ACE HARDWARE PHILS., INC.</site>
        <grossAmount>55.80</grossAmount>
        <discount>-0.50</discount>
        <netAmount>-55.30</netAmount>
    </article>
   <article>
        <transCode/>
        <poNumber>20239479</poNumber>
        <docRef/>
        <site>ACE HARDWARE PHILS., INC.</site>
        <grossAmount>0.00</grossAmount>
        <discount>80.44</discount>
        <netAmount>8,928.62</netAmount>
        </article>
</body>
<footer>
       <totalAmount>0.00</totalAmount>
       <ewtAmount>0.00</ewtAmount>
       <arItcc>0.00</arItcc>
       <netPayable>13,570.80</netPayable>
       <importantRemarks><![CDATA[Please review your Details of Payment immediately. Discrepancy noted should be reported within 60 days from credit date. Any request for reconciliation beyond this period shall not be given priority.]]></importantRemarks>
</footer>
</MT_RemittanceAdvice>
```

Result of system-property

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <systemProperties>
    <xslVersion>3.0</xslVersion>
    <xslVendor>Saxonica</xslVendor>
    <xslVendorURL>http://www.saxonica.com/</xslVendorURL>
    <xslProductName>SAXON</xslProductName>
    <xslProductVersion>HE 9.8.0.2</xslProductVersion>
    <xslIsSchemaAware>no</xslIsSchemaAware>
    <xslSupportsSerialization/>
    <xslSupportsBackwardCompatibility>no</xslSupportsBackwardCompatibility\
 </systemProperties>
```

Comment: So for which line and expression do you get that error? And does that SAP engine support XSLT 2.0? You can check `system-property('xsl:version')`, as https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/processorTest3.xml does, to find out. I would also try to write `<xsl:if test=" .intersect current-group()">` as `<xsl:if test=". intersect current-group()">`.

Comment: Now possible to XSLT2.0 based on this blog: [link](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/10/14/how-to-import-and-use-xslt-20-mappings-in-sap-pipo/).  I also tried <xsl:if test=" .intersect current-group()">, got the same error.

Comment: added my source XML

Comment: Your XSLT processor does not compile the stylesheet you have posted and you have not provided any clue on for which line and expression you get that error and whether you have tested whether `system-property('xsl:version')` returns `2.0` for that processor. The source XML does not help with that problem.

Comment: Hello, not able to pinpoint which line specifically as it is only providing this error message: "Transformer Configuration Exception occurred when loading XSLT RA_Split.xsl; details: Could not load stylesheet.com.sap.engine.lib.xsl.xpath.XPathException: Operator or ')' expected."      As for processor, currently using SAXON9HE, which should be compatible with XSLT2.0

Comment: Well, we can't debug that for you, try to run a stylesheet testing `system-property('xsl:version')` the same way you run the posted stylesheet where you get that error from `com.sap.engine.lib.xsl.xpath.XPathException`.

Comment: As requested, ran the system-property from the SAP Server.  Results posted above.

Comment: I tried your code (had to add a closing `</xsl:stylesheet>`) with Saxon 9.8.0.2 HE from the command line and it works without problems. I am not familiar with how it integrates with SAP, you might want to ask their support or add tags specific to the used technology so that someone with expertise related to it is able to help out.